# Empty DataFrame, Sorted by current date, in pandas

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Please help me, I need the data sorted in current date, when running it says:

> Empty DataFrame
>
> Columns: [DATE, TIME, FROM, TO, Vehicle, REQUESTOR]
>
> Index: []

Here's my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

import datetime

from tkinter import *

import pandas as pd

class Root(Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Root, self).__init__()
        self.geometry("900x500")
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        print("Current date and time : ")
        print(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
        self.label1 = tk.Label(self, text=now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), font="Helvatica 20 bold") 
        self.label1.place(x=750, y=0)
        self.data = pd.read_excel(r'pandas_simple.xlsx', sheet_name="UNO")

        self.booleans = []
        self.booleans[:]
        self.numero1 = pd.Series(self.booleans)
        self.numero1 = self.data.DATE == now.strftime
        self.numero1.head()
        self.data[self.numero1]
        print(self.data[self.numero1])

        self.current = tk.Label(self, text=self.data[self.numero1], bg="ORANGE", width=68, height=13)
        self.current.place(x=1, y=3)

jona = Root()

jona.title("BOOKING CHORVA")

jona.mainloop()
```

Comment: Well, I am not really sure what you are trying to achieve here.. You can not sort an empty dataframe? Please make more clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: i've an excel data in this file 'pandas_simple.xlsx', i want to sort it by the current date (because there's and dataframe there name DATE)  and display the data in my tkinter.

Comment: then try `df.sort_values('date',ascending=True,inplace=True)`

Answer (score 0):

In this part it should:

self.numero1 = self.data.DATE == now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")